# Remove Windows Firewall requirement for adding printers

Tags: windows-7, windows, firewall, windows-server-2003

Is there a way to remove the requirement Windows 7 has to have the firewall enabled to add a shared printer to the computer?

Comment: Not sure its possible. I supposed you could open some ports, but thats about it. How could your firewall know if its printer traffic or not?

Comment: It is possible, just make a rule

Comment: Instead of the question about the firewall, what are you actually trying to do? For example, I am trying to add an HP xxx printer to Server 2003 32-bit, share it, and then access it from Windows 7 64-bit. To a question like that, I can probably give you a very definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start > [type in] Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > [enter] > Actions > New Rule > (under rule type) Predefined Rules > *** File and printer sharing *** > Next > Check all the boxes you want > Next > Allow the Connection > finish.

Note:
When you add a program to the list of allowed programs in a firewall you allow a particular program to send information to or from your computer through the firewall. Allowing a program to communicate through a firewall (sometimes called unblocking) is like opening a tiny door in the firewall.
Each time you allow a program to communicate through a firewall, your computer becomes a bit less secure. The more allowed programs your firewall has, the more opportunities there are for hackers or malicious software to use one of those openings to spread a worm, access your files, or use your computer to spread malicious software to others.
To help decrease your security risk:
Only allow a program when you really need to, and remove programs from the list of allowed programs that you no longer need.
Never allow a program that you do not recognize to communicate through the firewall.